# How to fetch acount holder name in twilio PHP?

Tags: php, twilio

I am using PHP to fetch my twilio log details.

code :

```
foreach ($client->account->calls as $call)
     {
           $sid = $call->sid;

           $call_sid = $call->parent_call_sid;

           $tocaller = $call->to;

           $fromcaller = $call->from;

           $caller_name = $call->caller_name;
           $direction = $call->direction;
           $account_sid = $call->account_sid;

           $nosid = $call->phone_number_sid;

           $status = $call->status;

           $duration = $call->duration;
           $date_created = $call->date_created;

           $price = $call->price;
}
```

but in `$call->from` i am getting a phone number, basically i want the the user name for that caller as it is giving a name under from column in twilio log details page

Comment: why are you assigning `$call->something` to `$something`? seems somewhat pointless if you use it in the `foreach()`? Just refer to $call->something directly... or am I missing something.

Comment: basically i am inserting all call logs into my database and there are about 100 entries in my call log

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

It sounds like you are either looking for the Client name or the Caller ID for your call, both of which are parameters returned from the [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#instance-properties). In cases where you are receiving a call from Twilio Client, `$call->from` will be the name of the Client page. In cases where you are receiving a call from a phone line, the number will be in the `$call->from` parameter.

For caller ID, the `$call->caller_name` parameter will be populated if your phone number has been enabled for Caller ID lookup in your dashboard.